# image border firefox only fills corners

Tags: firefox, repeat, css

When I use the border image property, four squares show up, one in each corner, but nothing on the sides.  What am I doing wrong?

```
height:400px;
width:200px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:60px;
 border-left-width:60px;
border-image:url("images/red2.png") 20 20 20 20 stretch;
-webkit-border-image:url("images/grid.png") 20 20 20 20 stretch;
-moz-border-image:url("images/pattern.png") 20 20 20 20 repeat;
-ms-border-image:url("images/grid.png") 20 20 20 20 repeat;
-o-border-image:url("images/red2.png") 20 20 20 20 repeat;
position:fixed;
```

Comment: A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be helpfull

Comment: Mr. Alien is right, please post a fiddle with the html and css you are using.